# Let an Image glow on a black Background on an Image

Tags: html, css, image, filter, background

I've got the following HTML code:

```css
.header-container {
  position: relative;
}

.header-container img {
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%) contrast(300%);
  filter: grayscale(100%) contrast(300%);
}

.header-container .after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  color: white;
  background-image: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2a/ITunes_12.2_logo.png/600px-ITunes_12.2_logo.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: contain;
}

.header-container:hover .after {
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 10px #ff5f00);
  filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 10px #ff5f00);
}
```

```html
<div class="header-container">
  <span class="image fit"><img src="http://images.wookmark.com/167422_battlefield-dinosaur-facebook-timeline-cover-facebook-banner.jpg" alt="" /></span>
  <div class="after">This is crazy</div>
</div>
```

I would like to have a glow around the logo image (works). Unfortunately, I cannot cover the header image with a black background like this:

```
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
```

When I do this, the whole header area gets black and not only the logo image. How can I let the logo image glow, when there's a black background on top of the header image? I hope, you can understand my problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your image to glow you either have to add the glow in photoshop. You could also add your logo as a text and add `text-shadow:1px 1px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);` with your wished glow color.